# How can I access the connection string in my Web.Config file through a Windows Application

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have my Entity Connection String set in my Web.Config file. In the same solution, I have a Windows Application, and I want to access the Connection String of my Entity. How can I access the connection string that exist in my Web.Config file? Or I have to create a specific one in my Windows Application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're unfamiliar with adding a config file to a windows app, you must select an "Application Configuration File" from add new items, it will create a file named App.Config which will at compile time become YourProgramsName.exe.config but internally it works mostly just like a web.config with an appsettings section and connectionstrings sections and all the other normal sections.

The best way to share this data between Web and Win config files would be:

Create a separate file that looks like:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Name" 
     providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" 
     connectionString="Valid Connection String;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and reference it from both config files with:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
</configuration>
```

Then just add the connections.config (add existing item **by link**) to each project.

More reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx

Comment: `<add name="San2011Entities" connectionString="my connection string" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />` How can I put the `providerName  in this case ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos the element you are referencing there goes into the separate file, inside the connectionStrings section.

Answer (score 0):

Put the connection string your windows application's `App.config`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: but this will acess my Web.Config file that exist in a different project in my solution ?

Comment: -@Lucas_Santos:set special name for each connection string